# Virtualenv and pip on a mac, does it pickup the environment automatically?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

Does python's pip with virutalenv automatically detect the virtualenv based on the folder you are on (similar to how ruby and rvm does)?

i.e. I may have many virtual environments, and as I just through projects it will automatically change the environment?

Comment: That is an interesting idea though: to automatically activate a virtualenv if you are in the directory. Full of security issues, though (automatically execute '. bin/activate' if .Python exists in the current dir?).

Comment: I find this idea really interesting, if others consider it usefull or not please add comments to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/290

Answer (score 1):

No, virtualenv's are *not* activated based on your current working directory.  To activate a virtualenv, run the `source ../bin/activate` command from the folder of the specific virtualenv you wish to activate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, it won't. I've recently started using [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/), which provides you with a quick and easy set of commands to create and switch between virtualenvs. Whilst not exactly an answer to your question, you may find this of some use.